# Change class using Javascript, set one element's class opposite by default

Tags: javascript, class, default, background-color

Firstly, I realise my question may be relatively similar to some other posts, however, I tried implementing code from other posts but just couldn't get it to work the way I wanted. I'm pretty new to Javascript so please bear with me.

I have a selection of links within separate div elements made to look like tabs. Every time I click on a different link the background colour changes from grey to white for the active one and the previously active links' background colour changes from white to grey.

Here's my conundrum: I want a default setting for the Home link so it has a white background when the page loads.

Here's the code:

```
    div.none {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px 15px 3px 15px;
    }

    div.active {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px 15px 3px 15px;
    }

    ...

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var selected = null;

    function toggleClass(x) {
        if (selected != null)
            selected.className = 'none';

        selected = x;
        x.className = 'active';
    }

    </script>

    ...

    <div class="none" id="t1"><a class="menu" href="#1.html" onclick="toggleClass(t1)" target="tabs">Book Online</a></div>
    <div class="none" id="t2"><a class="menu" href="#2.html" onclick="toggleClass(t2)" target="tabs"> Contact</a></div>
    <div class="none" id="t3"><a class="menu" href="#3" onclick="toggleClass(t3)" target="tabs">News</a></div>
    <div class="none" id="t4"><a class="menu" href="#4" onclick="toggleClass(t4)" target="tabs"> Mobile Recording</a></div>
    <div class="none" id="t5"><a class="menu" href="#5" onclick="toggleClass(t5)" target="tabs"> Recording Studios</a></div>
    <div class="none" id="t6"><a class="menu" href="#6" onload="toggleClass(t6)" onclick="toggleClass(t6)" target="tabs">Home</a></div>
```

Thank you in advance if you can help!

Comment: Is that just me, or you forgot to ask your question at the end...?

Comment: Here's my conundrum: I want a default setting for the Home link so it has a white background when the page loads. That's my question.

Answer (score 1):

Change the initial class to `'active'` for the home link...?

Comment: When I set the Home link as active it displays the backround colour as white permanently.

Comment: start `selected` as your home tab instead of null. For the record, this looks like an awful way to do tabs. You shouldn't have any JS in your HTML, and you shouldn't have to manage the state in the JS, especially if you are labeling with classes.

Comment: how would I implement this please?

Answer (score 0):

Add the class active to the div which has the link for Home (at design time)

```
<div class="none active" id="t6"><a class="menu" href="#6" onload="toggleClass(t6)" onclick="toggleClass(t6)" target="tabs">Home</a></div>​
```

However, you will still have to write the logic in your javascript to remove that class when some other tab is selected and add the `active` class to the selected tab.

Comment: I just realised I left onload in my code, my thinking was that it would change the class to active when the page loaded up. Is there any way to implement this? I just tried what you said but it just keeps the Home link background colour as white permanently.